# A connected compact manifold has a unique orientable line bundle on it

Tags: manifolds, vector-bundles, line-bundles

How to show that if $M$ is a connected compact manifold there is upto isomorphism a unique orientable line bundle on it and that the line bundle is trivial iff $M$ is orientable?

Comment: Hint: There are two classes of isomorphism of the real line as a vector space. Now look at the possible local trivializations.

Comment: Since $H^1(M;Z_2)=Z_2$, I get that there are two isomorphism classes of real line bundles. What to do after that?

Comment: If you know about the classification theorem, maybe you know about characteristics classes. The vanishing of the first Stiefel-Whitney class is a necessary and sufficient condition for a real vector bundle to be orientable. See Milnor's book, Characteristic Classes.

Comment: @aritracb, why is that H^1 equal to Z/2Z?

Comment: You probably need to change "compact" by "closed" in your hypothesis. Thanks to Mariano for his accurate comment. For example, the closed ball of dimension $n$ is a contractible manifold.

Comment: @Laz can you please give the full argument? Why can't there be two orientable line bundles on an orientable $M$?

Comment: yeah sorry, its closed.

Comment: I was just wondering, over non-orientable $M$, $M\times R$ has $w_1=0$ but the assertion seems to imply it is non-orientable.

Comment: Whether $M$ is orientable or not, $M\times\mathbb{R}$ has $w_1=0$, because it is trivial. Do not confuse orientability of a manifold, which amounts to orientability of it's tangent bundle, with the orientability of any other bundle over it.

Comment: To prove that orientable implies trivial, take a finite system of local trivializations over open balls in $M$. If the bundle is orientable, each transition function can be chosen as $\phi_{\alpha\beta}(p,t) = (p,g_{\alpha\beta}(p)(t)$, where $g_{\alpha\beta}(p)$ is an orientation preserving isomorphism of the fiber. Can you modify this transition to make it less complicated?

Comment: Mustn't the minimum of all the $g_{\alpha\beta}(p,t)$ be a positive number? This is enough to come up with an isomorphism. You are free to use a metric if it makes your argument easier.